# Azure DocumentDB, Is it possible to JOIN a list from a certain document to the query?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Here what I like to do,
I would like to find all documents where their field "Color" is on the list of colors.

It is possible to run "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Color IN (colorList)

The problem is the list of colors is way to big for a query.

Comment: Can you please explain why "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Color IN ('blue', 'green', ... ) does not work? What error do you see returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit on the number of elements you can include in an `IN` clause. I think it's 100 though so it might actually be enough for colors. If that's not enough, then your only option is to break it down into chunks smaller than the limit, run separate queries, and concatenate the results. You could even run them in parallel. You could do all of this in a stored procedure (sproc) but for a batch of parallel reads it's usually best to just fetch directly to the client as it allows DocumentDB to read from secondaries.

Comment: Minor update: there is no limit any longer on number of arguments to IN.

Comment: Cool, but there is still a limit on the length of a query request so not unbounded but still good. Thanks for the update.